# Removing existing file in a directory

Tags: bash

I'm trying to check if a directory if existing file, if so then I would like to remove the file before moving new file in that directory.

```
if [[${abc_directory}/filename*.dmp]] ; then
rm -rf ${abc_directory}/filename*.dmp
```

I think I am missing some logic in the if statement.

Comment: Whenever you have a shell script error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Answer (score 2):

Simply do:

```
rm -f "${abc_directory}"/filename*.dmp
```

The option `-f` (`--force`) tells `rm` to ignore non existing files.

I have not included `-r`, because following your description, you will remove single files and not directory trees.

I have escaped the `${abc_directory}` part to avoid issues with spaces. It assumes, that `abc_directory` doesn't contain any wanted wildcards/placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

You're not looking for a specific file in your example, you're using a wild card. Why not just do a `rm -rf ${abc_directory}/filename*.dmp` before moving in the new file and be done with it?

Here's how to check for existence of a single file.

```
if [ -e ${abc_directory}/filename.dmp ];then 
   rm -f ${abc_directory}/filename.dmp
fi
```

Comment: It' s useless to check the existence of a file, if the only reason is to remove it by `rm -f ...` (-f == --force). Simply call  `rm -f ...`.